# Emuators for testing App, is there a specific range you should test on

Tags: android, android-emulator

```
Android Studio 0.4.5
```

Hello,

I am getting ready to deploy my first App (just a simple App) I am wondering what emulators should you test on.

I have 2 hardware phones, Nexus5 and Acer Z130.

As there are a lot of emulators is there any specific ones you should target.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a developer, you should test your application for its stability in maximum versions of android devices and also on different android versions too.
Use multiple emulators having different configurations and test your app